# messageboard style green text CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to style "greentext" for my Jekyll blog.

Given Markdown something like

```
implying implications\\
shiggidy diggidy\\
t. frogposter\\
unbased and cringepilled
(:.greentext}
```

Or HTML

```
<p class="greentext">implying implications<br>
shiggidy diggidy<br>
t. frogposter<br>
unbased and cringepilled</p>
```

The text should be colored green, have appropriate linebreaks and each line should look like it has a ">" character preceding it.

The obvious solution would be something like

```
.greentext {
  color: green ;
}
.greentext p {
  margin: 0 ;
}
.greentext p::before {
  content: '> ' ;
}
```

But this requires every line to be a paragraph which is awkward.

Also some screen readers will read out "> " as "greater than" which is annoying.

So I really want something more like

```
.greentext {
  color: green ;
  padding-inline-start: 1ch ;
  border-inline-start-style: solid ;
  border-width: 1ch ;
  white-space: pre-wrap ;
}
```

I feel like there ought to be a way to use `border-image` for this but I'm not really familiar with it.

Comment: Couple of things here. The markup in your first codeblock isn't Markdown, I'm not sure what that syntax is but I'm guessing it's an extension in Kramdown? You could do the formatting when you build the blog (not sure about Jekyll specifically but there must be a way!) and set `aria-hidden="true"` on a span around the `>` to skip in screen readers.

Comment: Or you could also use a `before` on a span around each line if you can generate the HTML that way and fix the screen reader issue [by providing empty alt text](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content#syntax): `span::before { content: '>' / ''; }`, though this isn't supported in all browsers.

Comment: @ZacAnger I didn't really feel like writing a plugin but it's definitely possible. I was hoping there was a better way. I didn't know about the content alt text. I'll look into that. Yeah I'm using Kramdown sorry.